# How to reuse jquery function

Tags: jquery

Hey guys I have a problem with re-using code:

```
YT_ready(function() {
  $("iframe[id]").each(function() {
      var identifier = this.id;
      var frameID = getFrame(identifier);
      if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
          players[frameID] = new YT.Player(, {
              events: {
                  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
          });
      } 
  });
```

});

tried this..

```
   slide('code', function() {
   YT_ready();
   });
```

Comment: Which part of the code do you want to reuse exactly? The initialization of the player?

Comment: Try `function YT_ready() {};` instead of the anonymous (?) function you have now.

Comment: It's in jQuery so it won't work if I use function YT_ready();

Comment: YT_ready() seems to come from YouTube API. The guy has set an anonymous function as a handler and wants to reuse the same handler elsewhere, but can not reference it, because the function has no name.

Comment: Ohhhh haha! I fixed it thanks @MKaama

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var handler=function(thi) {
  $("iframe[id]").each(function() {
      var identifier = thi.id;
      var frameID = getFrame(identifier);
      if (frameID) { //If the frame exists
          players[frameID] = new YT.Player(, {
              events: {
                  'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
              }
          });
      } 
};
YT_ready(function(){handler(this)});
slide('code', function(){handler(this)});
```

I had to add some wrapping to get the correct value of **this** into the handler.